# Can I pass data between Remote Hooks and Operation Hooks in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs

I can pass data between operation hooks by using the ctx.hookState property. Is there something like that for sharing data between remote and operation hooks?

When I acquired some data in the remote hook, how do I access it in the operation hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data only between hooks of the same type only

Comment: You can implement some 3rd party storage (for example - in memory, redis, etc) and work with it but this is not loopback way.